# I have an incoherent and chaotic UV map

Tags: uv, error

[image: preview of a weird colored model and his retarded UV map]

my UV map is completely incoherent, pieces are spread all over the map without bigger sense, on the left is my model when all I wanted to color were eyebrows and nose

I first modeled my model, then I tried to add textures, but then I realized she has no eyebrows, co I join them, I wanted also modify a bit her nose to be easier to color

When I return to textures, eyebrows were added ON the map, causing this weird coloring

I would like to know if there's a way to re-create the map so the pieces won't lay on one another
I didn't apply the mirror and sub-surface modifiers and my model has every part (like eyes, scarf, T-shirt etc.) in an another "layer" (that thing on the top right). I'm writing this if it can help.

I'm a lil concerned, it's my first 3D model and I don't want to re-model the whole thing :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.
First step: delete the map (make a backup copy of the .blend file first).

Then you should try the several unwrapping options. If you don't find one that make a good map, you could try unwrapping the mesh in more steps (some faces per time). For example you could map the two symmetric halves separately.